# What does 'directs' mean?

Tags: meaning

In a work setting, as in "They had to present their project to his directs."

Does it mean people who work directly under him, above him, or someone else?

Comment: Presumably they mean "direct reports" -- his immediate underlings.  Business jargon.

Answer (score 3):

While you have not provided adequate context to know for certain here, in business jargon, *direct* is short for *[direct report](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/direct-report)*, which refers to

> an employee whose position at work is directly below that of another person, and who is managed by that person

as per the *Cambridge Business English Dictionary*. To *[report to](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/report-to)* someone is to be under their supervision; to *directly* report to someone is to do so without any intervening layers or convoluted arrangements. A worker might be a direct report to a manager, who is a direct report to a director, who is a direct report to a vice president. Even though the worker, like everyone else in the department, ultimately reports to the vice president, she is a *direct* report only to the manager.

It is not common to refer to subordinate employees as *reports* in general, and this sense is not given in the OED, for example.  I suspect it is a relatively recent coinage that allows one to distinguish between the relationship between two adjacent rungs on the corporate ladder and those more distantly removed. It also avoids terms like *subordinate* or *underling* which may have unpleasant connotations of hierarchy.

The earliest Google Books example I could turn up is from a [1992 court case](https://books.google.com/books?id=AziTAAAAIAAJ&q=%22direct%20report%22), and *direct report* is set off in quotation marks, suggesting its use was not yet widespread.